# Android How to handle click events and sliding of the same area by two view

Tags: android, onclick, ontouchlistener

[As shown in figure a layout, ViewGroup (green color) + View (red part)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQn0Y.png)

operating within the scope of the red (View), click on the event by the View response, sliding by ViewGroup response, could you tell me how to achieve this requirement should be, thank you.